# Is there a way to get the real modified time of a file?

Tags: command-line, files, security, time

You can set an arbitrary time using the `touch` command, is there a way to get the real modified time of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `touch` can set is the “atime” or “mtime”.  POSIX systems also track the “ctime”, “inode change time”.  Several alternatives for getting it:

```bsh
$ ls -lc _file_
$ stat -c %z _file_
$ perl -MDate::Format -e '@_ = stat $ARGV[0]; print ctime $_[10]' _file_
```

Any change to the file's data or metadata (hard link count, permissions, etc.) sets the “ctime”.